# how to get value from textbox to alert

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net

I'm trying to get the value of the textbox `txtID` to show on alert message. I'm using this code for the alert:

```
Response.Write("<script language='JavaScript' >alert('Record successfully added!');document.location='" + ResolveClientUrl("Siteindex.aspx") + "';</script>");
```

It works just fine but when I try to insert the value of txtID on the alert...

```
Response.Write("<script language='JavaScript' >alert('Record '" + txtID.Text + "' successfully added!');document.location='" + ResolveClientUrl("Siteindex.aspx") + "';</script>");
```

The alert message isn't showing up, but the record is added. What seems to be the problem? Should I just use another alert code?

Comment: Are you getting the value in txtID.Text in code behind file ?

Comment: yes, i'm using it to find the row (table) for the record

Comment: Can you try adding the text at the end of the sentence...just in case to see if you missed any quotes ?

Comment: Try `txtID.Text.ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

May be some problem with escaped string:

Try like this

```
Response.Write("<script language=\"JavaScript\" >alert(Record " + txtID.Text + " successfully added!);document.location=" + ResolveClientUrl("Siteindex.aspx") + ";</script>");
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra single quote there, use the below code

Response.Write("alert('Record " + txtID.Text + " successfully added!');document.location='" + ResolveClientUrl("Siteindex.aspx") + "';");

Comment: Are not even getting any client side error in the web developers tool on chrome or ie developer.. console tab ?

Answer (score 0):

Do you use **UpdatePanel** wrapping the add button? If so, you have to set **PostBackTrigger** for that button.

I mean like this sample code

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server"><ContentTemplate>
        <asp:TextBox ID="txtID" runat="server" ></asp:TextBox>
        <asp:Button ID="btnAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btnAdd_Click" />
</ContentTemplate>
    <Triggers>
        <asp:PostBackTrigger ControlID="btnAdd" />
    </Triggers>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Where the **btnAdd** button was handled by **btnAdd_Click** to add the recoreds, and run the alert script

```
Response.Write("<script language='JavaScript' >alert('Record " + txtID.Text + " successfully added!');document.location='" + ResolveClientUrl("Siteindex.aspx") + "';</script>");
```

Comment: no i don't use UpdatePanel.. the code is just inside the btnAdd_Click event

Comment: Strange! I don't get any errors until I wrap the btnAdd button by **UpdatePanel**, the script above should work in **btnAdd_Click**. Could you provide me your part of asp code?